# How to change "Next" & "Previous" link icon in Ajaxtoolkit's CalendarExtender?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax, calendarextender

I created a web application with a calendar extender using vs2008. In viewing the calendar i wanted to change the images of the next and previous button inside the header of the calendar. is there anyway that i can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have tested over the VS2010 and it worked.

This css code will **modify the underlying class** for the previous and next month images of the CalendarExtender

```
    .ajax__calendar_prev
    {
        background-image: url(Images/anyImage.png) !important;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_next
    {
        background-image: url(Images/anyImage.png) !important;
    }
```